# How to combine keys in nested list of rules or associations?

Tags: list-manipulation, associations

Considering we have a list of rules:

```
lst = {"A" -> {"A1" -> {"a.124" -> "45", "a.125" -> "45"}, 
    "A2" -> "something", 
    "B" -> {"b[1].sqw" -> "true", "b[1].ewq" -> "false", 
      "b[2].tyy" -> "saved", "b[2].bfg" -> "iid:"}, "C" -> "eb9d"}}
```

Note*: I know that the delimiter is always a point - `.`

How can I "combine" the keys and make another list of vales having as a result:

```
res = {"A" -> {"A1" -> {"a" -> {"124" -> "45", 
        "125" -> "45"}}, "A2" -> "something", 
    "B" -> {"b[1]" -> {"sqw" -> "true", "ewq" -> "false"}, 
      "b[2]" -> {"tyy" -> "saved", "bfg" -> "iid:"}}, "C" -> "eb9d"}}
```

### UPDATE

A real data example:

```
{"crs" -> {"BlueHue" -> "0", "BlueSaturation" -> "0", 
   "CameraProfile" -> "Adobe Standard", "ColorNoiseReduction" -> "25",
    "ColorNoiseReductionDetail" -> "50", "Contrast2012" -> "0", 
   "DefringeGreenHueHi" -> "60", "DefringeGreenHueLo" -> "40", 
   "Exposure2012" -> "+0.45", "GreenHue" -> "0", 
   "GreenSaturation" -> "0", "HasCrop" -> "False", 
   "HasSettings" -> "True", "LuminanceSmoothing" -> "0", 
   "ParametricShadowSplit" -> "25", "ParametricShadows" -> "0", 
   "PostCropVignetteAmount" -> "0", "RedHue" -> "0", 
   "RedSaturation" -> "0", "Saturation" -> "0", 
   "SaturationAdjustmentAqua" -> "0", 
   "SaturationAdjustmentBlue" -> "0", 
   "SaturationAdjustmentGreen" -> "0", 
   "SaturationAdjustmentMagenta" -> "0", 
   "SaturationAdjustmentOrange" -> "0", 
   "SaturationAdjustmentPurple" -> "0", 
   "SaturationAdjustmentRed" -> "0", 
   "SaturationAdjustmentYellow" -> "0", "ShadowTint" -> "0", 
   "Shadows2012" -> "+25", "Sharpness" -> "103", 
   "SplitToningHighlightSaturation" -> "0", 
   "SplitToningShadowSaturation" -> "0", "Temperature" -> "3700", 
   "Tint" -> "+16", "ToneCurveName2012" -> "Medium Contrast", 
   "ToneCurvePV2012" -> 
    "0, 0, 32, 22, 64, 56, 128, 128, 192, 196, 255, 255", 
   "ToneCurvePV2012Blue" -> "0, 0, 255, 255", 
   "ToneCurvePV2012Green" -> "0, 0, 255, 255", 
   "ToneCurvePV2012Red" -> "0, 0, 255, 255", "VignetteAmount" -> "0", 
   "WhiteBalance" -> "As Shot"}, 
 "dc" -> {"creator" -> "unknown", "format" -> "image/jpeg"}, 
 "photoshop" -> {"DateCreated" -> "2014-04-28T14:52:32"}, 
 "xmp" -> {"CreateDate" -> "2014-04-28T14:52:32", 
   "CreatorTool" -> "Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 5.0 (Macintosh)", 
   "MetadataDate" -> "2014-04-28T16:11:27-05:00", 
   "ModifyDate" -> "2014-04-28T16:11:27-05:00", "Rating" -> "5"}, 
 "xmpMM" -> {"DerivedFrom" -> {"DerivedFrom.documentID" -> 
      "45DA984AC12B4C2E29FD2841B1732B26", 
     "DerivedFrom.originalDocumentID" -> 
      "45DA984AC12B4C2E29FD2841B1732B26"}, 
   "DocumentID" -> "xmp.did:8669ed4e-bda9-48dd-80cd-4fd3aeef1e06", 
   "History" -> {"History[1].action" -> "derived", 
     "History[1].parameters" -> 
      "converted from image/x-canon-cr2 to image/jpeg, saved to new \
location", "History[2].action" -> "saved", 
     "History[2].instanceID" -> 
      "xmp.iid:8669ed4e-bda9-48dd-80cd-4fd3aeef1e06", 
     "History[2].when" -> "2014-04-28T16:00:23-05:00", 
     "History[2].softwareAgent" -> 
      "Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 5.0 (Macintosh)", 
     "History[2].changed" -> "/", "History[3].action" -> "saved", 
     "History[3].instanceID" -> 
      "xmp.iid:6c92b810-3d29-4c6c-8565-a7f150f0eb9d", 
     "History[3].when" -> "2014-04-28T16:11:27-05:00", 
     "History[3].softwareAgent" -> "Adobe Photoshop CC (Macintosh)", 
     "History[3].changed" -> "/"}, 
   "InstanceID" -> "xmp.iid:6c92b810-3d29-4c6c-8565-a7f150f0eb9d", 
   "OriginalDocumentID" -> "45DA984AC12B4C2E29FD2841B1732B26"}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
splitAndGroup[list_List]:=Module[{splitedList},
    splitedList=MapAt[StringSplit[#,"."]&,list,{All,1}];
    Normal@GroupBy[splitedList,(#[[1,1]]&),MapAt[Last,{All,1}]]
]

convert[list_List]:=Map[splitAndGroup,lst,{-3}]
```

Now using:

```
lst = {
   "A" -> {"A1" -> {"a.124" -> "45", "a.125" -> "45"}, 
   "A2" -> "something", 
   "B" -> {"b[1].sqw" -> "true", "b[1].ewq" -> "false", 
      "b[2].tyy" -> "saved", "b[2].bfg" -> "iid:"},
   "C" -> "eb9d"}
}
```

You can do `convert@lst` to get:

```
   {
     "A"->{"A1"->{"a"->{124->45,125->45}},
     "A2"->"something",
     "B"->{"b[1]"->{"sqw"->"true","ewq"->"false"},
           "b[2]"->{"tyy"->"saved","bfg"->"iid:"}}
    ,"C"->"eb9d"}
   }
```

And if you need it in `Association` form:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
ToAssociations@convert@lst

 <|
  "A"-><|"A1"-><|"a"-><|"124"->"45","125"->"45"|>|>,
  "A2"->"something",
  "B"-><|"b[1]"-><|"sqw"->"true","ewq"->"false"|>,
         "b[2]"-><|"tyy"->"saved","bfg"->"iid:"|>|>,
  "C"->"eb9d"|>
 |>
```

### Update

For the real case, there are lists that should not be splited. Like this one:

```
"dc" -> {"creator" -> "unknown", "format" -> "image/jpeg"}
```

Just add a `If` in `splitAndGroup`, like this:

```
splitAndGroup[list_List]:=Module[{splitedList},
    splitedList=MapAt[StringSplit[#,"."]&,list,{All,1}];
    If[Length@splitedList[[1,1]]==1,Return@list];
    Normal@GroupBy[splitedList,(#[[1,1]]&),MapAt[Last,{All,1}]]
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I have posted an update with a real data that I use. Your function gives a strange result for that data. Could you please comment? Thanks!

Comment: @SuTron I believe now it works as you expect.

Comment: You are a Genius! :)

Comment: @SuTron glad in help!